# Multiple datasets on the same scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I want to plot multiple data sets on the same scatter plot:

```
cases = scatter(x[:4], y[:4], s=10, c='b', marker="s")
controls = scatter(x[4:], y[4:], s=10, c='r', marker="o")

show()
```

The above only shows the most recent `scatter()`

I've also tried:

```
plt = subplot(111)
plt.scatter(x[:4], y[:4], s=10, c='b', marker="s")
plt.scatter(x[4:], y[4:], s=10, c='r', marker="o")
show()
```

Comment: Its overprinting on the same line.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

You need a reference to an `Axes` object to keep drawing on the same subplot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(100)
y = range(100,200)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.scatter(x[:4], y[:4], s=10, c='b', marker="s", label='first')
ax1.scatter(x[40:],y[40:], s=10, c='r', marker="o", label='second')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What does `111` in `fig.add_subplot(111)` mean ?

Comment: It's the arrangement of subgraphs within this graph. The first number is how many rows of subplots; the second number is how many columns of subplots; the third number is the subgraph you're talking about now. In this case, there's one row and one column of subgraphs (i.e. one subgraph) and the axes are talking about the first of them. Something like fig.add_subplot(3,2,5) would be the lower-left subplot in a grid of three rows and two columns.

Comment: What if I need to plot three scatter plots instead of two shown here?

Comment: @NixMan nothing changes, it works with the same setting

Answer (score 40):

I came across this question as I had exact same problem. Although accepted answer works good but with matplotlib version `2.1.0`, it is pretty straight forward to have two scatter plots in one plot without using a reference to `Axes`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(x,y, c='b', marker='x', label='1')
plt.scatter(x, y, c='r', marker='s', label='-1')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can I use the same approach for a third scatter plot? 

Like, plt.scatter(x, y, c='g', marker='o', label='-2')

Answer (score 9):

I don't know, it works fine for me. Exact commands:

```
import scipy, pylab
ax = pylab.subplot(111)
ax.scatter(scipy.randn(100), scipy.randn(100), c='b')
ax.scatter(scipy.randn(100), scipy.randn(100), c='r')
ax.figure.show()
```

Comment: My datasets were overlapping :)