# How to plot in python where x-axis values appears more than once, like 0 1 2 3 2 1 0

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm new to python, and was playing around with it's plotting capability. I wanted to plot `Y1` and `Y2` where `X` values go from 10 to 100 with steps of 10, and 100 to 10 with steps of -10.

I was able to plot this using Excel. 
Here are the `X` and `Y` values

```
X  = [10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 100 90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10]
Y1 = [0 100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 900 800 700 600 500 400 300 200 100 0]
Y2 = [100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 1000 1000 900 800 700 600 500 400 300 200 100]
```

How do we plot something like this in python using `matplotlib` and `numpy`?

Comment: Unless you're asking someone else to plot the data for you, I don't see a need to dump them here.

Comment: It'll be also nice to see what have you tried so far.

Comment: nebuch- I just wanted to be as clear as possible. It's actually hard to explain this in words, and thus I created a sample data set in excel

Comment: Please share some code what you have tried so that people have better understanding.

Comment: I don't see what's difficult here, just use a scatter plot for both data series as demonstrated in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4270437/1093485

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its unclear exactly what you are asking. Do you want the repeated `X` values to plot on top of each other? In which case, you can use `ax.plot` as shown in the first example (`ax1`) below.

If you want the X axis to show all the `X` values in the order they appear in your list, you could use scatter, then just set the `xticklabels` to the values in `X`, as shown in the second example below (`ax2`)

As stated above in comments, neither of these are particularly difficult: there are lots of examples in the [`matplotlib` gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X  = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10]
Y1 = [0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 900, 800, 700, 600, 500, 400, 300, 200, 100, 0]
Y2 = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1000, 900, 800, 700, 600, 500, 400, 300, 200, 100]

fig = plt.figure()
ax1=plt.subplot(211)
ax2=plt.subplot(212)

# First example: overlap repeated X values
ax1.plot(X,Y1,'ro')
ax1.plot(X,Y2,'bo')
ax1.set_title('ax.plot')

# Second example: keep all X values in sequential order
ax2.scatter(range(len(Y1)),Y1,color='r')
ax2.scatter(range(len(Y2)),Y2,c='b')
ax2.set_title('ax.scatter')
ax2.set_xlim(0,len(Y1)-1)
ax2.set_xticks(range(len(Y1)))
ax2.set_xticklabels(X)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't HAVE to use numpy to plot with matplotlib. You can use normal python lists for plotting with matplotlib. NumPy is the package for scientific computation with Python. Its used for its great capabilities for handling matrices. Doing the matrix operation with standard lists is slower. That's why numpy is great.

You can read about numpy [here](http://www.numpy.org/)!

You can take help from this [link](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) for plotting data with pyplot. Tweak around the parameters to see what you find.

Also I am providing this simple code for plotting. I assume you know how to use `import` in python.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = [range(0,100,10)]
Y = [range(0,1000,100)]

plt.scatter(X,Y)
plt.show()
```

If you insist on using numpy you can change the code of these two portions

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([range(0,100,10)])
Y = np.array([range(0,1000,100)])
```

Comment: The OP is asking for a single plot to list both his datasets. Therefore, your solution does not work and he will need to use an `axes` object.