# How can I plot over repeating x-axis values, without using x-values from data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis

I know there are similar questions already answered ([How to plot in python where x-axis values appears more than once, like 0 1 2 3 2 1 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32263913/how-to-plot-in-python-where-x-axis-values-appears-more-than-once-like-0-1-2-3-2)), however in that problem the x-values where used as the x-axis values.
The main difference is that my data points (x) are not equidistant to each other (see data_df below) and I want to plot over a fixed x-axis, not strictly related to the x-values. My measurement window goes from 3.5 to 4.9 and then back from 4.9 to 3.5, so e.g. `range = [3.5, 3.6,...,4.8, 4.9, 4.8,..., 3.6, 3.5]`.

What I want to do is to have 'range' as my x-axis and plot my data_df according to this axis.
I guess what I want is
[image: this semi-goal image].

However, in one plot (one x- and y-axis) instead of two separate plots.

I feel like I tried everything so far I could find on stackoverflow, but i guess my limited experience with python and matplot stands in my way. Here is what I tried so far:

data_df is this DataFrame:

```
[[4.2, 416394000.0], [4.55, 417501000.0], [4.68, 418680000.0], [4.73, 417273000.0], [4.76, 416939000.0],
 [4.77, 417441000.0], [4.78, 418144000.0], [4.79, 418832000.0], [4.78, 419445000.0], [4.79, 419811000.0],
 [4.8, 419832000.0], [4.81, 419727000.0], [4.8, 419669000.0], [4.8, 419691000.0], [4.8, 419676000.0],
 [4.81, 419775000.0], [4.81, 419698000.0], [4.81, 419729000.0], [4.81, 419684000.0], [4.82, 419435000.0],
 [4.82, 419201000.0], [4.81, 418755000.0], [4.83, 418273000.0], [4.84, 413020000.0], [4.84, 411498000.0],
 [4.85, 409950000.0], [4.86, 407930000.0], [4.87, 405948000.0], [4.88, 403255000.0], [4.89, 401120000.0],
 [4.9, 399124000.0], [4.67, 401493000.0], [4.65, 401813000.0], [4.63, 401349000.0], [4.62, 399976000.0],
 [4.61, 398104000.0], [4.6, 395457000.0], [4.59, 392566000.0], [4.58, 389359000.0], [4.57611, 385742000.0],
 [4.56588, 381776000.0], [4.5568, 377795000.0], [4.54503, 373427000.0], [4.53287, 369763000.0],
 [4.51665, 365492000.0], [4.49696, 61393000.0], [4.47187, 357905000.0], [4.44002, 353489000.0],
 [4.39678, 349760000.0], [4.33945, 346221000.0], [4.2659, 343530000.0], [4.17517, 342173000.0],
 [4.04198, 341340000.0], [3.87693, 340104000.0], [3.74161, 333359000.0], [3.41905, 328130000.0]]
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_df = ...

#creating xticks
ticks = np.arange(3.5, 4.9, 0.1)
ticks = np.append(ticks, np.arange(4.8, 3.5, -0.1)

#plotting
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7.5))
ax = plt.subplot()
plt.xticks(ticks)
ax.scatter(data_df.x, data_df.y)
plt.show()
```

I was expecting that `plt.xticks` goes through ticks in a sequence and sets all values as individual ticks. However, I got this:[image: this].

Instead of going through each element and adding it to the x-Axis the values from 4.8 to 3.6 are duplicated.

I also tried splitting data_df manually into the two ranges (3.5-4.9 and 4.9 to 3.5) and plotting them in one figure. Different way, same outcome.

I also tried it with `ax.set_xticks` and `ax.set_xticklabels` without success.

Here the 'minimal reproducible example':

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_df = pd.DataFrame([[1.0, 3], [1.1, 4], [1.5, 6], [1.55, 8], [2.0, 10], [1.8, 8], [1.81, 7], [1.4, 6],[1.2, 4]],
                       columns = ['x', 'y'])

xticks = np.arange(1, 2, 0.1)
xticks = np.append(xticks, np.arange(2, 0.9, -0.1))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot()

plt.xticks(xticks)

ax.scatter(data_df.x, data_df.y)
plt.show()
```

The expected/wanted outcome:

[image: outcome].

Help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Do you mind to format properly your dataframe?

Comment: I hope this is better?

Comment: You could make the ticks categorical, e.g. `ax.scatter(np.arange(len(data_df)), data_df.y)` followed by `ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(data_df)), data_df.x)`

Comment: @JohanC That plots the data in the right sequence, however the x-values are now also the x-axis values with equal distance on the axis, which I don't want since some of my data points are grouped together. This is why I wanted to use the ticks array for the axis which is decoupled from the values in my data.

Comment: Woould you mind to produce a very simple [mcve] and sketch your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Using `ax.set_xticks` and `ax.set_xticklabels` seems the right way to go. For example,

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = np.asarray(
    [
        [4.2, 416394000.0], [4.55, 417501000.0], [4.68, 418680000.0], [4.73, 417273000.0], [4.76, 416939000.0],
        [4.77, 417441000.0], [4.78, 418144000.0], [4.79, 418832000.0], [4.78, 419445000.0], [4.79, 419811000.0],
        [4.8, 419832000.0], [4.81, 419727000.0], [4.8, 419669000.0], [4.8, 419691000.0], [4.8, 419676000.0],
        [4.81, 419775000.0], [4.81, 419698000.0], [4.81, 419729000.0], [4.81, 419684000.0], [4.82, 419435000.0],
        [4.82, 419201000.0], [4.81, 418755000.0], [4.83, 418273000.0], [4.84, 413020000.0], [4.84, 411498000.0],
        [4.85, 409950000.0], [4.86, 407930000.0], [4.87, 405948000.0], [4.88, 403255000.0], [4.89, 401120000.0],
        [4.9, 399124000.0], [4.67, 401493000.0], [4.65, 401813000.0], [4.63, 401349000.0], [4.62, 399976000.0],
        [4.61, 398104000.0], [4.6, 395457000.0], [4.59, 392566000.0], [4.58, 389359000.0], [4.57611, 385742000.0],
        [4.56588, 381776000.0], [4.5568, 377795000.0], [4.54503, 373427000.0], [4.53287, 369763000.0],
        [4.51665, 365492000.0], [4.49696, 61393000.0], [4.47187, 357905000.0], [4.44002, 353489000.0],
        [4.39678, 349760000.0], [4.33945, 346221000.0], [4.2659, 343530000.0], [4.17517, 342173000.0],
        [4.04198, 341340000.0], [3.87693, 340104000.0], [3.74161, 333359000.0], [3.41905, 328130000.0]
    ]
)

# "mid" point in x
mid = 4.9

# get xvalues
x = df[:, 0]

# get index of the mid-point
midp = np.argwhere(x == mid)[0][0]

# create version of x axis that extends above the mid-point
x[midp + 1:] = 2 * mid - x[midp + 1:]

# create plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))
ax.scatter(x, df[:, 1])

# set new x-axis limits
ax.set_xlim([3.5, mid + (mid - 3.5)])

# set new x-tick positions and labels
xticks = np.arange(3.5, mid + (mid - 3.5), 0.2)
xticklabels = []

for xt in xticks:
    if xt > mid:
        # correct the label above the mid-point
        xticklabels.append(f"{2 * mid - xt:.1f}")
    else:
        xticklabels.append(f"{xt:.1f}")

ax.set_xticks(xticks, labels=xticklabels)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Both solutions work beautifully. Awesome community!

Comment: @jtAxiom Thanks. If solution's are useful and solve you problem please consider upvoting them (upvoting all answers is fine) and marking one or other as your accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution creating two subplots without blank space in between:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x', 'y'],
                       data=[[4.2, 416394000.0], [4.55, 417501000.0], [4.68, 418680000.0], [4.73, 417273000.0], [4.76, 416939000.0], [4.77, 417441000.0], [4.78, 418144000.0], [4.79, 418832000.0], [4.78, 419445000.0], [4.79, 419811000.0], [4.8, 419832000.0], [4.81, 419727000.0], [4.8, 419669000.0], [4.8, 419691000.0], [4.8, 419676000.0], [4.81, 419775000.0], [4.81, 419698000.0], [4.81, 419729000.0], [4.81, 419684000.0], [4.82, 419435000.0], [4.82, 419201000.0], [4.81, 418755000.0], [4.83, 418273000.0], [4.84, 413020000.0], [4.84, 411498000.0], [4.85, 409950000.0], [4.86, 407930000.0], [4.87, 405948000.0], [4.88, 403255000.0], [4.89, 401120000.0], [4.9, 399124000.0], [4.67, 401493000.0], [4.65, 401813000.0], [4.63, 401349000.0], [4.62, 399976000.0], [4.61, 398104000.0], [4.6, 395457000.0], [4.59, 392566000.0], [4.58, 389359000.0], [4.57611, 385742000.0], [4.56588, 381776000.0], [4.5568, 377795000.0], [4.54503, 373427000.0], [4.53287, 369763000.0], [4.51665, 365492000.0], [4.49696, 61393000.0], [4.47187, 357905000.0], [4.44002, 353489000.0], [4.39678, 349760000.0], [4.33945, 346221000.0], [4.2659, 343530000.0], [4.17517, 342173000.0], [4.04198, 341340000.0], [3.87693, 340104000.0], [3.74161, 333359000.0], [3.41905, 328130000.0]])
# split = np.where(np.diff(data_df['x'] )<0)[0][0] + 1
split = 31
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5),
                               sharey=True, gridspec_kw={'wspace': 0})
df_1 = data_df.iloc[:split]
df_2 = data_df.iloc[split:]
ax1.scatter(df_1['x'], df_1['y'])
ax2.scatter(df_2['x'], df_2['y'])

ax1.set_xlim(3.5, 4.9)
ax2.set_xlim(3.5, 4.9)
ax2.invert_xaxis()
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(0.1))
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(0.1))
ax2.yaxis.set_visible(False)  # hide y ticks of right subplot

ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)  # right spine of first plot invisible
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)  # left spine of second plot invisible
# ax2.spines['left'].set_color('red')
# ax2.spines['left'].set_linestyle((0, (4, 4)))

plt.show()
```

[image: two subplots without blank space]

Or with a dotted line to better visualize the differently spaced x-axis.

[image: two subplots with dotted separation]

Comment: Thank you! Both solutions work beautifully. Awesome community!