# Compare two distributions with different sizes using Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, distribution, seaborn, percentile

I want to compare two different distributions, where one has 100 data points, the other 150 data points.

In `seaborn` I am able to do it using `lmplot` in this way:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
sns.lmplot(x="dist1", y="dist2", data=df)
```

considering the input `pandas` DataFrame as composed by two columns `dist1` and `dist2`, each one having the same number of data points.

However, this only works with distribution of the same size. Therefore I was thinking about taking percentiles of each distribution. 
Is there already an implementation of such plot (e.g. in matplotlib, seaborn, statsmodels, plotly..)?

#### Edit

About closing votes: this question does not belong to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) SE because I am clearly asking about code or libraries API to compare two distributions, not theoretical questions about distributions or statistical methodologies to analyse them. Here for distribution I only meant: set of data points.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that want the two data sets on the same axis, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270301/matplotlib-multiple-datasets-on-the-same-scatter-plot). You need a reference to the axis to which you want to draw.

sample:

```
a = [1.1, 2.8, 14, 21, 23]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.scatter(range(len(a)), a)
ax1.scatter(range(len(b)), b)
```