# How to make scatter plot with matplotlib as shown

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw a scatter plot as shown in the figure but it seems that my code is not working the same as required, I am a begginer in python with not having much experience.

[image: graph_required]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Production_steps = [13,12,21,1,29,20,15,12,21,18,20,15,20,22,26,7,8,12,22,25,15,23,24,13,4,22,12]
Step_name = ['Start','NA2S','waiting','NA+','vacume','NA-','90min_Wait','waiting','NA+','waiting','vacume','vacume','1h_wait','Pressue','vacume','vacume','NA+/-','NA+','Pressure','90min_Wait','Pressure','cool-','vacume','vacume','NA-','Pressure','Batch Start']
Parameter1 = [80,932,21,525,20,20,21,1090,19,60,18,33,19,936,1083,61,102,1088,935,38,20,83,21,79,1006,930,1088]

# Create a DataFrame using the given data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Production_steps': Production_steps, 
'Step_name': Step_name, 'Parameter1': Parameter1})

# Get unique values of 'Step_name'
unique_steps = df['Step_name'].unique()

# Set up colors for each unique 'Step_name'
colors = plt.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(unique_steps)))

# Create a figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13, 6))

# Loop through unique 'Step_name' values, filter data, and plot scatter points
for i, step in enumerate(unique_steps):
  step_data = df[df['Step_name'] == step]
  ax.scatter(step_data['Production_steps'],step_data['Parameter1'], label=step, color=colors[i])

# Set labels and show legend
 ax.set_xlabel('Production_steps')
ax.set_ylabel('Parameter1')

# Create legend outside of plot to position it at the bottom
fig.legend(loc='lower center', ncol=4, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5,-0.2))

# Show the scatter plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: your code is not reproducible since it contains libraries and data that you haven't provided.  You should make an example that is fully reproducible. You could populate your dataframe with some toy data and import the needed libraries, so we can run the code. Posting a screenshot of the data is not useful for us, we need to be able to run your code in order to help you.

Comment: I'd suggest using a seaborn [`stripplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html)

Comment: @Elerium115 please check now the post

Comment: `NameError: name 'df' is not defined`. Looks like you haven't defined your `df` variable anywhere. Also the code inside the for loop is not indented, which will cause an error. You need to correct your errors for the code to be runnable.

Comment: Sorry @Elerium115 please check now if its working

Comment: ok, you are creating the figure inside the loop, which will create one figure for each iteration. you dont want that, move the figure creation outside the loop. it's not clear what part of your code is inside the loop and which not. That's why you should fix the indentation of the code

Comment: @Elerium115 I took it out from the loop but now the problem I am facing is that the production_step number is not referencing Step_name but it is referencing the Parameter1

Comment: If you see the image of graph requuired you might get it what i really want to say

Comment: Your question still have the code inside the loop without indentation. and I don;t see in the code of the question that you have taken anything out of the loop. Sorry, without you making the suggested modifications in the code I cannot further help you. Fix your indentation and take the figure out of the loop.  I don;t see how taking `plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))` can possibbly cause the problem you describe

Comment: Thanks @Elerium115 your suggestion quit helped alot the code is now wroking perfectly. I edited the code in the post also  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works perfeectly for my question.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Production_steps = [13,12,21,1,29,20,15,12,21,18,20,15,20,22,26,7,8,12,22,25,15,23,24,13,4,22,12]
Step_name = ['Start','NA2S','waiting','NA+','vacume','NA-','90min_Wait','waiting','NA+','waiting','vacume','vacume','1h_wait','Pressue','vacume','vacume','NA+/-','NA+','Pressure','90min_Wait','Pressure','cool-','vacume','vacume','NA-','Pressure','Batch Start']
Parameter1 = [80,932,21,525,20,20,21,1090,19,60,18,33,19,936,1083,61,102,1088,935,38,20,83,21,79,1006,930,1088]

# Create a DataFrame using the given data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Production_steps': Production_steps, 
'Step_name': Step_name, 'Parameter1': Parameter1})

# Get unique values of 'Step_name'
unique_steps = df['Step_name'].unique()

# Set up colors for each unique 'Step_name'
colors = plt.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(unique_steps)))

# Create a figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13, 6))

# Loop through unique 'Step_name' values, filter data, and plot scatter points
for i, step in enumerate(unique_steps):
  step_data = df[df['Step_name'] == step]
  ax.scatter(step_data['Production_steps'],step_data['Parameter1'], label=step, color=colors[i])

# Set labels and show legend
ax.set_xlabel('Production_steps')
ax.set_ylabel('Parameter1')

# Create legend outside of plot to position it at the bottom
fig.legend(loc='lower center', ncol=4, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5,-0.2))

# Show the scatter plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: I tried this code. It basically crashes instead of running perfectly because of the line that is only indented with one space. This answer should not be accepted, since the proposed code doesn;t work.

Comment: @Elerium115 I edited the code, this should work now.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create the figure outside of the loop and reference an axis as for instance described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270301/multiple-datasets-on-the-same-scatter-plot).

```
# First, create the figure and an axis object
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot()

# Then loop through your 'layers' and (re)use the axis object
for value in df['Step_name'].unique():
    filtered_df = df[df['Step_name'] == value]
    ax.scatter(
        x=filtered_df['Production_steps'],
        y=filtered_df['Parameter1'],
        label=value,
    )

plt.xlabel('Production_steps')
plt.ylabel('Parameter1')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Because *value* changes in each iteration, it does not make sense to use it in the title. That - and of course proper indentation - should do the trick.